# Python function that can compute cube roots, fourth roots, fifth roots and so on?

Tags: python, math

I am trying to make a function `root(x, y)` where it finds the yᵗʰ root of x.

I have tried to use `math.sqrt()` here, but it doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
def root(x, y):
    for i in range(y):
        math.sqrt(x)

for i in range(10000):
    print(root(i, 2))
```

And what it gives me:

```
None
None
None
None
None
```

and so on...

Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: You do not return anything. You do not store whatever your computation does. I do not see a serious attempt for an [mre] or any sign of debugging attempts...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `n`th root of `x` is just `x ** (1.0/n)`, which you can evaluate directly in Python.  Examples:

```
>>> 27 ** (1.0 / 3)
3.0
>>> 

>>> 32 ** (1.0 / 5)
2.0
>>> 

>>> 10 ** (1.0 / 6)
1.4677992676220695
>>>
```

In Python 3, you can use `1 / n` in place of `1.0 / n`, even if `n` is an integer, but I use `1.0` just to make it clear that it's a floating point divide.

Answer (score 1):

```
def root(x, y):
    return x**(1/y)
```